How to restrict content-types on direct upload from browser to S3 secured via pre-signed URL?
I am trying to generate an uplaod presigned url where frontend is required to send the content type of file.
I see that if fronend doesnt send this content type and i remove content type in params everything works fine,
but in bucket the object has type as blank white space no type mentioned.
so i thought while downloading or while getting the object through presignedurl and get it will give some error
but still everything works fine
only thing i can think of is we can use that content type in backend for validation and can limit uplaod to specific content type like images videos or something else?
Can anyone please explainthe real use case
Thankss.
app.post("/api/posts/pre", async (req, res) => {
  const bucketName = 'usman.test.bucket';
  const { fileName, fileType } = req.body; // Get file name and file type from form data
// /frontend is responsible for providing the fileType information, while the backend handles the generation of the fileName and the pre-signed URL. This separation of concerns ensures that the application is more modular and maintainable.
// /If the frontend doesn't provide the fileType, the backend can assume a default file type, such as application/octet-stream, which is a generic binary file type.
  try {
    const params = {
      Bucket: bucketName,
      Key: fileName,
      ContentType: fileType,
    };

    const command = new PutObjectCommand(params);
    const signedUrl = await getSignedUrl(s3, command, { expiresIn: 3600 });

    res.json({ presignedUrl: signedUrl });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating pre-signed URL:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error generating pre-signed URL');
  }
});


Does this answer your question? Uploading file to S3 using a pre-signed URL

You need to use createPresignedPost which is described halfway down the article at https://medium.com/@Games24x7Tech/a-complete-guide-to-s3-file-upload-using-pre-signed-post-urls-9cb2d6cfc0ab, instead of PutObjectCommand(). The article is actually very unclear but I believe you have to call createPresignedPost() in your back-end (with secret AWS Credentials), pass the URL to the front-end and have the front end do a regular POST to the signed URL.
Old answer based on misinterpreted question:
When you open files from S3 directly in the browser, it works better when you have the correct content type and encoding.
Source: First-hand experience. I had some .json.gz objects saved without these headers, and when I try to open the URL it would not show me the json on the screen, instead it would cause a "Download" or "Save As" dialog to pop up.
Probably the same would happen if you have a .jpg image and want to display the image in the web browser instead of forcing the user to download it as a file.

res.set("Content-Disposition", inline; filename="${fileName}");
do this and everything works
you didn't got my question
Thanks though

As a user, where would I type this javascript code, if it's not already in your code? That makes no sense. I didn't downvote BTW. Perhaps your question is unclear to others. It seems clear to me. Unless you modify your code with some workarounds, you will have to set the correct content-type on the objects.

suppose frontend sends file xyz.pdf
in my backend i am getting content type and i am doing validation that only file type of png or jpg allowed
lets say this is done ill come to your point
now we want to get object
and we know thart Body from getObject returns a readbale stream so for browser to display properly i do Body.pipe(res)

That could work but I don't think it's a very smart way to do it. The PutObjectCommand will always succeed so you will have invalid files sitting on S3.

I think you got me wrong.
Nevermind.
Someone might actually tell/answer what i am looking for

Yes but your code is very clear. It just uploads the file to S3 without any validation.

I just told the use case,
i am here to ask
thats why i posted
https://medium.com/@Games24x7Tech/a-complete-guide-to-s3-file-upload-using-pre-signed-post-urls-9cb2d6cfc0ab
i think this says how validation might work

Ok I see now. You want to restrict the filetypes that are allowed by uploading with pre-signed POST. In this case your code is completely wrong. I think you need createPresignedPost which is halfway down the article, instead of PutObjectCommand().

I edited your title and updated my answer.

Got it,thanks i think i was unclear about the validation part
